# How to display better text message if someone's enter wrong E-mail id?

Tags: user-expectation, text, error-message, content

How can we display a better text message when a user enter wrong mail id on any mobile application he/she is using ?

Would - "Ugh, You entered an incorrect mail, please check again and fill the text box" that be okay or is there any better way we can formulate the content?

Answer (score 2):

"Urgh, you entered the wrong email" entirely depends on the audience and your brands tone of voice. Personally, it feels a bit of blame game and pointing the finger at the user, so not particularly encouraging. Don't feel you have to go for something humourous, error messages are designed to be informative and provide a resolution for the user.

Take a look at these best practices

https://www.nngroup.com/articles/error-message-guidelines/

https://uxplanet.org/how-to-write-good-error-messages-858e4551cd4?gi=54f679750f2f

I'm assuming this is for a username and password, so how do you know the password is not incorrect therefore not authorising the user? Make sure your error message is suitable for all errors that are returned.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion, I'll look into the links.

Answer (score 1):

"No user with this email" would be fine, I guess.

What to do if the email was actually correct? "This is my real email, what do you mean it is incorrect?" Checking again will not help in this situation. Tell a user, what else to do (register with this address, ask someone to create new account).

Comment: Cool, thanks for your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

> Ugh

This is very emotive, and it's going to mean different things to different users, dpeending on their understanding, culture, etc. To me, for example, "ugh" is an expression of digust or frustration, so that's what I'd think if I saw it in an interface. Is that the impression you want to give  - that the application or your organisation is exasperated with the user?

> You entered an incorrect mail

Say exactly how it's incorrect - too long, too short, contains an invalid character, etc. This will give the user the clue they need to fix the problem and move on.

> please check again and fill the text box

Again, be specific about what the user needs to do to rectify the issue.